# Can't seem to find the lower bound for this function

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Been reading about algorithms. I am trying to find the lower and upper bounds for the function f(n). not very familiar with mathjax so i used mathtype. how do i proceed with the lower bound. especially the denominator.
[image: Can't post image so here's the link]
also, is the upper bound $24n$ the tightest possible bound ?

Comment: The best upper bound in the sense you are looking for, is $\frac {19}{5}n+1.$

Comment: @user376343 i am looking for both bounds in the form $0<=c_1.g(n)<=f(n)<=c_2.g(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An bound for $f$ is simply
$$
\frac{19}{5}n \le f(n)\le \frac{19}{5}n + 1
$$
for all $n\ge 1$. This follows from $0\le 1-\frac{1}{n}\le 1$. Usually for the algorithm one just says that $f$ is in $O(n)$. So you could also take any estimate like $f(n)\le 10^6n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: i am looking for the form $c.g(n)$. also how do i got about finding the lower bound

Comment: just take $c=1$ and $g(n)=19n/5$.

Comment: ok. but if $g(n)$ is not the same for both the bounds then we can't say $f(n)$ is $\Theta(n)$ , right?

Comment: @Awaisome Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120540/how-to-determine-if-a-function-f-is-in-thetag), or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560344/how-to-prove-big-theta-on-polynomial-function?rq=1) etc. Have you tried to search yourself already?

Comment: well i took hint from what you said above that $0\le 1-1/n\le 1$ and solved lower bound for $19n/5$. already had the upper bound $24n$. could you confirm if these are right? i mean i am fairly new to this stuff and i don't know for sure if i these are right, secondly as i asked above, if the $g(n)$ for both bounds come out to be different (like $c_1.logn^2\le f(n)\le c_2.n^3$), that means $f(n)$ is not in $\Theta(n)$, right?