# Prove using the definition of θ.

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, data-structure

How I can prove that:
$$
((n^2) − 3*n + 2) ∈ θ(n^2) 
$$
using the definition of $θ$ ?

θ : an asymptotic notation in data structure algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'm unsure what you mean by "using the definition of $\theta$." Is $\theta(x^2)$ a function on $x$?

Comment: Uh, that depends on what the definition of $\theta$ *is*.  What the heck *IS* the definition of $\theta$?

Comment: 0. [Big Theta Proof on polynomial function](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14344/83577), 1. [Big-O Notation - Prove that $n^2 + 2n + 3$ is $\mathcal O(n^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437098/318073), 2. [How to prove Big Theta on polynomial function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2560344/318073), 3. [How to prove any polynomial of degree k is in Θ(nk)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21298/83577), ...

Comment: θ : an asymptotic notations in data structure algorithm.

Comment: @ola : Others are right that you should have provided your working definition of $\Theta$ (that's \Theta not \theta) in the body of your Question.  There are variations in the definitions of asymptotic notation (contrast Knuth's $\Omega$ with the number theoretic version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to find, on $n \in [1,\infty)$, the minimum and maximum of
$$  \frac{n^2 -3n + 2}{n^2}  \text{.}  $$
Let $\ell$ be the global minimum and $u$ be the global maximum.  Then you know
$$  \ell n^2 \leq n^2 - 3n + 2 \leq u n^2  \text{,}  $$
where $\ell$ and $u$ are constants (independent of $n$).  This establishes the result you want.

In this particular case, there is a critical point giving the lower bound, $-1/8$, and then you can take a limit to get the upper bound, $1$.

Of course, since $\Theta$ allows the bounds to hold on any interval of the form $[n_0, \infty)$.  You can choose to optimize on a smaller half-line.  If, say, you optimize on $[5,\infty)$, the rational function above is strictly monotonically increasing, so you can evaluate the ratio at $5$ to get a lower bound and take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (which is very, very easy for rational functions and is taught prior to calculus when graphing rational functions) to get an upper bound.